# Is there any way to change dictonary items comparing with another one?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

```
import json
from urllib import request

infile = request.urlopen('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/all')

content_as_python_obj = json.loads(infile.read().decode())

name=[]
boarder=[]
code=[]

for country in content_as_python_obj:
name.append(country['name'])
    boarder.append(country['borders'])
    code.append(country['alpha3Code'])



countryAndCode=dict(zip(name, code))
countryAndBoarders=dict(zip(name, boarder))
```

#I would like to replace the codes with the full name to have a dictionary that states the name and the bordering countries with the full name

Comment: can you post a sample input and expected output

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the mapping of country code to country name to convert all the country code present in the `borders` list.

```
country_code_to_country_name = dict(zip(code, name))
country_borders = dict(zip(name, boarder))

country_borders = {
    key: [country_code_to_country_name[v] for v in value]
    for key, value in country_borders.items()
}
```